Unreliability attenuation correction affects Cohen's d and its standard error. How do I use uncertainty propagation to estimate the correct SE?
Assume I am using Cohen's d to quantify some kind of effect. Since Cohen's d is defined (simplified) as $$d = \frac{MD}{\sigma_x}$$ $MD$ reflects a differences in means, which is standardized by the pooled standard deviation $\sigma_x$. Its size is clearly affected by the uncertainty in whatever variable I used. Assuming I did not measure that variable perfectly (in terms of score reliability, aka purely random measurement error), the pooled standard deviation $\sigma_x$ is increased, which implies an attenuation in $d$.
However, I can use attenuation correction formulae to correct the observed effect size for its score unreliability. The simplest case, where I have an estimate of pooled score reliability, looks like:
$$d_c = \frac{d}{\sqrt{\hat\rho_{xx'}}}$$
Here, $d_c$ corresponds to the corrected, disattenuated estimate of Cohen's d, whereas $\hat\rho_{xx'}$ corresponds to the estimate of pooled score reliability.
However, the standard error of Cohen's d is not variance-stable, implying that the standard error depends of the size of Cohen's d itself:
$$\text{SE}_d = \sqrt{\frac{N_1 + N_2}{N_1 N_2} + \frac{d^2}{2(N_1 + N_2 - 2)}}$$
Since Cohen's d grows as a result of the attenuation correction, we need to adjust the corresponding standard error as well.
Hunter & Schmidt (2004) write that the standard error can be corrected as defined in the folloing:
$$SE_{d_c} = SE_{d}\frac{d_c}{d}$$
Since $d_c$ is bound to be larger than $d$, $SE_{d_c}$ is bound to be larger than $SE_{d}$. However, if I am understanding this correctly, this does not incorporate the uncertainty introduced by employing an estimate of score reliability $\hat\rho_{xx'}$. This would imply that I need to assume to know the true (population value) of score reliability for this SE-correction to be correct.
I want to work with estimates, not with population values (since I do not have these at hand). I believe I can use uncertainty propagation, to incorporate the uncertainty of employing estimates in the attenuation correction. However, unfortunately I don't know how to do this and haven't been able to find the right text to do so.
I'd greatly appreciate any help on how to arrive at the right estimate, just like any pointers on how to use uncertainty propagation in such a case. Thanks!
